# Terraform: Creating maps with matching key fails with "duplicate object keys"

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a map of secondary ranges for the GCP VPC module [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/network/google/latest/submodules/subnets) and have the following defined in my locals:

```
  secondary_ranges = {
  for name, config in var.subnet_config : config.subnet_name => [
      {
        range_name    = local.ip_range_pods
        ip_cidr_range = "10.${index(keys(var.subnet_config), name)}.0.0/17"
      },
      {
        range_name    = local.ip_range_services
        ip_cidr_range = "10.${index(keys(var.subnet_config), name)}.128.0/17"
      }
    ]
  }
```

subnet_config is defined as follows:

```
subnet_config   = {
    cluster1 = {
        region           = "us-east1"
        subnet_name      = "default"
    },
    cluster2 = {
        region           = "us-west1"
        subnet_name      = "default"
    }
}
```

This creates the secondary subnets just fine if the subnet names are unique but fails with the error below if the subnet names (which end up being the key values) are not unique:

```
Two different items produced the key "default" in this 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after the value expression to enable grouping by key.
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can use grouping mode if the value is a list and if so, how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Map keys must be unique. You will need to use a different data structure for tis. Instead of making `secondary_subnets` a `map(list)`, you could make it `list(map)`.

Comment: Unfortunately the input expects a `map(list)`. I thought about passing a dynamic block to the module, but I'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: Can you edit to show more of what you need the final data structure to look and how it's used? Reading again I think I misunderstood the goal.

Comment: I have a link to the module in the question (put it below just in case). I am trying to dynamically define a list of subnets / secondary subnets for the vpc module:

https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/network/google/latest/submodules/subnets

I can add the subnet definition if that helps but that works as expected it is a `list(map)`

Comment: Changed the variable name to secondary_ranges to match the module.

Comment: Looking at this more closely, there is a bigger issue because you are relying on map order from keys(), which returns in lexical order, not the order they are defined.

Comment: secondary_ranges in that module ins't going to allow duplicate range keys, which I assume is the "name". You could use `"${config.subnet_name}.${config.region}"` as the key to ensure it's unique.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Even if I wanted to I can't create matching subnet names with that module (just verified). I'll have to change how I do that then. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you use [the grouping mode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/for.html#grouping-results) in this case then it would be to group the outermost `for` expression, which is producing a map, because that's the one whose keys you'd be grouping by.

We can start by adding the grouping mode modifier to that and see what happens:

```
 secondary_ranges_pairs = {
   for name, config in var.subnet_config : config.subnet_name => [
     {
       range_name    = local.ip_range_pods
       ip_cidr_range = "10.${index(keys(var.subnet_config), name)}.0.0/17"
     },
     {
       range_name    = local.ip_range_services
       ip_cidr_range = "10.${index(keys(var.subnet_config), name)}.128.0/17"
     }
   ]...
 }
```

The effect of the expression above would be to create a map of lists of lists of objects, where the deepest lists are each pairs of objects because of how your inner `for` expression is written.

To turn that into the map of lists of objects which I think you're hoping for, you can then use [`flatten`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html) in a separate step:

```
  secondary_ranges = {
    for k, pairs in local.secondary_ranges_pairs : k => flatten(pairs)
  }
```

`flatten` recursively walks a data structure where there are lists of lists and concatenates all of the nested lists together into a single flat list.

---

A word of caution: you seem to be using a lexical sort of the `subnet_config` keys in order to derive network numbering. That means that if you add new elements to your `var.subnet_config` whose keys sort earlier than any existing ones (for example, if you were to add in a `cluster0` into what you showed in your question) then you'll implicitly renumber all of the subsequent networks, which is likely to cause a lot of churn recreating objects, and the change might not even be possible if those networks contain other objects.

I'd typically recommend instead being *explicit* about what number you've assigned to each network, by including then as part of the `var.subnet_config` objects. You can then clearly see which numbers you've assigned and make sure that any new networks will always be assigned a later number without disturbing any existing assignments.

There's also an official Terraform module [`hashicorp/subnets/cidr`](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/hashicorp/subnets/cidr/latest) which aims to encapsulate subnet numbering calculations. The design of that module means that it wouldn't be completely straightforward to adopt it for your use-case (since you're allocating two levels of subnet at once) but it might be useful to study to see whether any of the design tradeoffs made there are relevant to your module.